# What is the brand/model of my bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I just bought this bike and I searched a lot about the brand/model of it but I can't find anything, please do you have any idea? I appreciate it!

[[image: 1]]

[[image: 2]]

[[image: 3]]

Comment: Its old - mid 1990's. My first though was a home modified hardtail to make a Full sus, but its more likely either very early prototype Full Sus or what we call BSO.  What country is it from? Whats is the problem you want to solve.

Comment: It at least isn't a generic frame, but has several unusual features.  "Carhartt" is a clothing brand, but they apparently license the name to Pelago and possibly some other bike manufacturers.  Googling `carhartt bike` brings up a lot of bike images, but nothing resembling your picture.

Comment: (The chain appears to be badly rusted.)

Comment: I posit that the carharrtt sticker is nothing more than a sticker and is nothing to do with the bike.  @DanielRHicks it looks like a sticker, not a decal or transfer.

Comment: The quill stem and boots over the front suspension stanchions suggest 90s.

Comment: @OP I googled "tnt cycles spain" and fiound https://www.yelp.com/biz/t-n-t-cycles-vilablareix-2  and   https://www.megamo.com  may be relevant.  Why Spain?  Cos Secguridad is Spanish for Safety.   Are you in Spain, or Europe ?

Comment: Regardless what it is, I should not care to ride it. Looks badly rusted and chain stay weld looks cracked.

Comment: It’s a really bad way to add rear suspension to a bike as it loses all of the lateral stability and strength of a diamond frame. Just one hard landing that’s slightly off balance will crumple the rear. Good for selling BSOs though.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Given Carhartt make cold weather/hiking clothes, this being a Canadian bike becomes a little more likely.

Comment: @OP You could now spend some time searching google images  https://www.google.com/search?q=ccm+mtb&source=lnms&tbm=isch    and see if you find a closer match.

Answer (score 2):

Not the same frame design but still a CCM, which stands for **Canada Cycle and Motor**

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_(bicycle_company)) article on CCM
- http://www.vintageccm.com/
- https://momentummag.com/story-of-canada-world-class-bike-company-ccm/

[image]

Comment: Interesting - the upstand brace on the top tube is very similar.  The shock mounting pictured here is under the top tube not on the downtube, but its still remarkably similar.   The forks looks similar in beefiness but lack the protective boots on the stanchions.  Your forks are dual crown whereas OPs are single crown.   Yours has disk brakes and OPs is rim brakes.   So whatever this is seems to be several years newer but in the same genetic lineage.  Could be a more "downhill" version or could have had an uprated fork fitted.

Comment: I have merged your two answers together.